# Basilisk II how mount unix filesystem

Tags: emulation, apple-macintosh

I use Linux Bassilisk II
I setup unix path
but how I can read file from it?
It not appear in my desktop

[image]

My system is in .sit file, how I can read file?

Comment: Which version of Basilisk II are you using?

Comment: To get in ahead of the potential issue that Basilisk issues are not retrocomputing issues: Basilisk II hasn't been substantially updated in at least 15 years, having seen only very broad maintenance in that period. I say this for the purpose of fair evaluation; it may or may not be persuasive.

Comment: @Tommy, but since it's not updated, makes it ideal candidate for Retrocomputing. A retro emulator for a retro system :)

Comment: @Tommy Just because something isn't updated for a while doesn't make it retro. Just Microsoft :))

Comment: There are forks which are still updated, including at least one which has dropped support for directory-sharing (hence my comment above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my `~/.basilisk_ii_prefs` file I have this line:

```
extfs /home/user/BasiliskShared
```

Which shares the `BasiliskShared` directory to Basilisk/Classic Mac OS. You'll see a `Unix` icon on the Mac desktop.

Tested with System Software 7.5.5 and Mac OS 8.1. Host system, Debian Linux, Buster.

---

After OP's comment, it seems that System 7 or 7.0.1 on Basilisk cannot provide a shared folder between host and emulated system.

Comment: I wrote before. I setup it but not work

Comment: It could be due to your System Software version, you use 7 or 7.0.1. Try 7.5.5 if possible.

Comment: yes, you are right. thanks. Please wrote answer here